# Ctrl + / for commenting does not work anymore in JupyterLab

Tags: python, comments, jupyter-lab, ctrl

I have been commenting (multiple) lines for quite some time using ctrl + /, as it is way quicker than adding # for each line. Suddenly I'm not able anymore to comment lines this way, and I cannot find any answers online. I see that there is keyboard shortcuts section in settings, but don't know how to make sure I can do this again. I have been using Microsoft Edge for +1 years.
Anyone else who has run into the same problem?

I've been looking online for similar problems and try adjusting the settings.